# Adding Multiple Edit Text(Around 60) in the same Activity layout in SqlLite database

Tags: java, android, xml

i am new to Android and **SqlLite** database, i am working on an survey application, problem comes when i add multiple Edit Text in the same activity layout(around 60), App gets pretty slow  and gives an error(paint operations) `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, i have increased  max heap size accordingly but still error remains the same.

How can i add  multiple Edit Text in the same activity layout(around 60)??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subject_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_update"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_update"
        android:layout_below="@+id/family_edittext"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gender_edittext"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/gender_edittext"
        android:layout_marginTop="800dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_delete"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_update"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_update"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_update" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Village Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/description_edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/subject_edittext"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/subject_edittext" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C.D. Block"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/description_edittext"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/description_edittext" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/village_edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/village_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/village_edittext"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/village_edittext" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/gender_edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age of the respondent"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gender_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView8" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/age_edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_update"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_update" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Family position of the respondent"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView11" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/family_edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_update"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_update" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Religion and caste of respondent \n 1.Hindu 2.Muslim 3.Christian 4.Jain 5.Sikh 6.Other. "
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/family_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/religion_editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/familycode"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/familycode" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Caste\n1.General 2.Schedule Caste (SC) 3.Schedule Tribe (ST) 4.Other Backward Caste (OBC) 5.Other "
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/religion_editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/caste_editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/religion_editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/religion_editText" />**strong text**

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Household members"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eeducation_editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/educationlevel_editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Household members: \nRelationship with the HH: \nAge: \nSex: \nMarital Status : \nLevel of education: \nCurrent occupation/livelihood:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total monthly income earned by the family from various sources? "
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/educationlevel_editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/income_editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

...............................................and so on




</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What does the sqlite database have to do with your view?

Comment: Nothing, but i was just telling that i'm working on sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom ListView or ExpandableListView for showing multiple edittext in your layout.

Comment: I'm Already using ListView  for showing multiple Edittext but i want to add multiple Edit Text in the same activity layout :(

Comment: generate dynamic edit-text is much time taking for me :(
is there any other way 
thanks in advance.

Comment: No bro, I don't know any other way. but You can modify your code for fast generate dynamic edit-text. follow http://prasans.info/2011/03/add-edittexts-dynamically-and-retrieve-values-android/ link

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav i will try that :)